# Replace string by an other variable with a string

Tags: javascript, string, function, variables, d3.js

I have this function:

```
var chart = d3.parsets()
        .dimensions(["Survived", "Age", "Class"]);
```

I want to replace `["Survived", "Age", "Class"]` with a string from an other variable. So i can change it. In this example: `.dimensions(["Survived", "Age"]);`

What i have is:

```
var strDimensions = ('"Survived", "Age"');

var chart = d3.parsets()
    .dimensions([strDimensions]);
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: What does `var strDimensions = ('"Survived", "Age"');` mean anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var strDimensions = ('"Survived", "Age"');

var chart = d3.parsets()
    .dimensions([strDimensions]);
```

What you are getting is an array with one index, not two.

If you want to use the string, you can split it to make it into an array.

```
var strDimensions = ('Survived,Age');

var chart = d3.parsets()
    .dimensions(strDimensions.split(",");
```

Why don't you just start off with the array to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Your array syntax is wrong, try this instead:

```
var strDimensions = ['Survived', 'Age'];

var chart = d3.parsets().dimensions(strDimensions);
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is

var dims = [];

now you can add and remove from the array as you wish

and then use

var chart = d3.parsets().dimensions(dims);